# Python fileConfig issue

Tags: python, logging, flask, flask-restful

I was following [this tutorial](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2016/06/19/building-beautiful-restful-apis-using-flask-swagger-ui-flask-restplus/) to run [app.py](https://github.com/postrational/rest_api_demo) they provided.

With the first try of running app.py I had an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/GIT_repos/SBD/rest_api_demo/rest_api_demo/app.py", line 11, in <module>
    logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
  File "C:\Users\hunte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\logging\config.py", line 76, in fileConfig
    formatters = _create_formatters(cp)
  File "C:\Users\hunte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\logging\config.py", line 109, in _create_formatters
    flist = cp["formatters"]["keys"]
  File "C:\Users\hunte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\configparser.py", line 956, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'formatters'
```

Errors vanished after I have replaced
line 11 in app.py:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
```

to

```
logging.config.fileConfig('../logging.conf')
```

**Question**
Was code of the tutorial faulty or is it something I did **&** What may be the cause, that other people doing this tutorial (I assume, looking at the comments) didn't have to change anything, while I had to?

Answer (score 1):

Your fix is legitimate - loading `logging.conf` is based on relative path, so `logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')` won't work.

Maybe this error is not mentioned in comments because people do not use boilerplate from GitHub as a scaffold for their project - I guess they simply skim through the tutorial and get interesting snippets selectively, avoiding the error.

I think you should propose the fix with a pull request on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Convert relative path into system absolute path should fix this issue:

```
logging_conf_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'logging.conf')
logging.config.fileConfig(logging_config_file_path)
```